# Calculate Probabilities of the occurrence of different Arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have 3 different arrays. Each array's cell contains different values. As given below:

```
array1 = array([[2702.703, 2702.703, 500.025],
          [1060.265, 300.2565, 2702.703],
          [2702.703, 2702.703, 2702.703]],
          dtype=float32)
array2 = array([[1000.235, 2702.703, 500.025],
          [1060.265, 300.2565, 2702.703],
          [2702.703, 2702.703, 200.2655]],
          dtype=float32)
array3 = array([[2702.703, 1500.326, 500.025],
          [4520.22, 300.2565, 2702.703],
          [2702.703, 1245, 2702.703]],
          dtype=float32)
```

I want to calculate probability of occurrence (by applying conditions less than 1000) at each positions of values in cell of 3 arrays and store this calculated probability values in new array.
For example OutPut:

```
array4 = array([[0.03, 0.2, 0.01],
          [0.22, 0.71, 0.9],
          [0.15, 0.45, 0.5]],
          dtype=float32)
```

Any related suggestions helpful.

Comment: Is this really a good StackOverflow question? Calculating probabilities?  Have you tried the stats part of Stackexchange? https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarkMoretto I have tried in different ways. but unable to apply on arrays. If you have any suggestion please put forward.

Comment: Could you clarify how you arrive at the probabilities in array4? It's not readily apparent to me how the values in the first three arrays result in the probabilities in the final array. It may be helpful to simplify your example (make it smaller or use numbers that make it easier to see the intended relationships between them).

Comment: @MatthewCox array4 is just given for example. The final calculation should look like this.  I have to calculate the probability between 3 arrays with conditions less than 1000. This probability calculation should be done at each cell value. Hope so you understand my concern

Comment: To make sure that I'm understanding you, are you looking for the percentage of values at that position that are < 1000?

Comment: Yes. suppose less than 1000 value appears in 2 arrays out of 3 arrays cell value. Then my probability will be P=(2/3) for that particular cell. It's like that

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - could you update your question to reflect that? It will help others with the same issue understand your question in the future.

Comment: Yes. I will do that. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to calculate the percentage of values meeting a condition in a position across arrays:

```
# First, stack all of the arrays along a new dimension (dimension 2)
stacked = np.stack([array1, array2, array3])
# Then apply your condition and get the mean of the values along your new dimension
# The mean function works by treating each True as a 1 and each False as a 0
result = (stacked < 1000).mean(axis=2)
print(result)
```

Output

```
   array([[0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.        ],
          [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333],
          [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.        ]])
```

Comment: This suggested method  calculation output, not showing the exact solution

Comment: I've updated the answer to show assigning the calculation to a variable, then printing that variable. If the final result is not what you're looking for, I may be still misunderstanding your question. If so, can you explain how you expect the result to be different?

Comment: I have reframed my question and put in new tab. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/65303662/14105784)